# How to reuse a method with different arguments without duplicating code

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar is complaining about this method which is duplicated code (The same exact method is available in two different Mapper classes)

**EventBasicMapper:**

```
private Optional<Date> getDoneDate(EventTable event) {
    var eventStatus = event.getEventStatus();

    if(eventStatus.getName().equals(EventState.DONE.getName())) {
        List<EventStatusLog> eventStatusLogs = event.getEventStatusLog();
        if(eventStatusLogs.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.of(Iterables.getLast(event.getLogs()).getDate());
        }
        return Optional.of(Iterables.getLast(eventStatusLogs).getModified());
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

**EventMapper**

```
private Optional<Date> getDoneDate(Event event) {
    var eventStatus = event.getEventStatus();

    if(eventStatus.getName().equals(EventState.DONE.getName())) {
        List<EventStatusLog> eventStatusLogs = event.getEventStatusLog();
        if(eventStatusLogs.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.of(Iterables.getLast(event.getLogs()).getDate());
        }
        return Optional.of(Iterables.getLast(eventStatusLogs).getModified());
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

The only difference between these methods is the argument: one receives an EventTable and the other receives an Event.
Is there a way i can reuse this functionality without duplicating the code? Is there any way i can call this method and pass a different data type paramether?

Hopefully i explained my issue here. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, extract the contents into a private function and have both call it

Comment: find a common interface shared by Event and Eventable (maybe Event itself)

Comment: interface is good, I like that better

Comment: If you can show us the models Event and EventTable, that would help

Answer (score 0):

Create a util class/ static method,
(assuming var eventStatus is of type T, replace T with your actual type here please)

Foo.class

```
public static Optional<Date> getDoneDate(T eventStatus) {

    if(eventStatus.getName().equals(EventState.DONE.getName())) {
        List<EventStatusLog> eventStatusLogs = event.getEventStatusLog();
        if(eventStatusLogs.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.of(Iterables.getLast(event.getLogs()).getDate());
        }
        return Optional.of(Iterables.getLast(eventStatusLogs).getModified());
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

now, **EventBasicMapper:**

```
private Optional<Date> getDoneDate(EventTable event) {
    return Foo.getDoneDate(event.getEventStatus());    
}
```

and **EventMapper:**

```
private Optional<Date> getDoneDate(Event event) {
        return Foo.getDoneDate(event.getEventStatus());    
    }
```